# IntelliJ IDEA complains about 'broken source path' for sbt-driven project

Tags: scala, path, sbt

I have to import ***scala*** project with `sbt`. Importing is ok. All dependencies is downloaded:

[image]

But at settings I see a bunch of errors:

[image]

This jars are downloaded. I couldn't figure out why this happen.

My test looks next:

[image]

***How to solve this trouble?***

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution was installing `SBT Execute` plugin:

Running from `SBT Commands` ***compile*** task.

After this execution all is fine compiled and worked.